# Authentication flow in Stack.Navigator issue

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

The flow I want to achieve is this:

**Expected behaviour:**

1. Show splash screen - loading screen *While doing all the auth checks in the background
2. After all the checks are done
3. Show the Authorized screens or the Unauthorized ones

**What is happening:**

1. Firstly the loading screen shows up for few seconds
2. ***Here is the issue*** - It shows the Unauthorized screen for few seconds and then it automatically redirects to the Authorized one (if the user !== null)

this is my code:

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const StackNavigator = () => {
  const { currentUserProfile } = React.useContext(CurrentUserProfileContext);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = React.useState(null);

  const getSignedInStatus = () => {
    const user = currentUserProfile.data;
    try {
      if (user !== null) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsSignedIn(true);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }, 3000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsSignedIn(false);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }, 3000);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getSignedInStatus();
  }, [currentUserProfile]);


  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  }

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {!isSignedIn ? (
        <Stack.Screen name="Unauthorized" component={Unauthorized} />
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen name="Authorized" component={Authorized} />
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default StackNavigator;
```